# How to check a scope variable containing an array of objects using karma unit testing in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have a scope variable

```
$scope.FacilityLocations = [
{ Id: 1, Name: 'All', value: 'all', Selected: true },
{ Id: 2, Name: 'Facility Location 1', value: 'facilityLoc_1', Selected: true },
{ Id: 3, Name: 'Facility Location 2', value: 'facilityLoc_2', Selected: false },
{ Id: 4, Name: 'Facility Location 3', value: 'facilityLoc_3',  Selected: false }];
```

and my testing code is...

```
it('Checking array of objects:',function() {
        expect($scope.FacilityLocations).toEqual([{ Id: 1, Name: 'All', value: 'all', Selected: true }, { Id: 2, Name: 'Facility Location 1', value: 'facilityLoc_1', Selected: true }, { Id: 3, Name: 'Facility Location 2', value: 'facilityLoc_2', Selected: false }, { Id: 4, Name: 'Facility Location 3', value: 'facilityLoc_3',  Selected: false }]);
    });
```

Please suggest me a solution to this problem, what I am missing out here.

Thanks in advance.

It is a duplicate of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43539882/how-to-check-a-scope-variable-containing-an-array-of-objects-in-karma-unit-testi)

Comment: please clearly mention what is not working for you? Maybe [`objectContaining`](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Partial_Matching_with_<code>jasmine.objectContaining</code>) ?

Comment: @tanmay could you help me with the correct syntax to check the array? I am not sure about `toEqual`..

Comment: Maybe you can use [`expect(arr).toContain("foo")`](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Included_Matchers) where foo can be replaced by your object(s).. read full documentation for that.. it's easier than your think

Comment: I am getting this error message `Expected undefined to equal [ Object({ Id: 1, Name: 'All', value: 'all', Selected: true }), Object({ Id: 2, Name: 'Facility Location 1', value: 'facilityLoc_1', Selected: true }), Object({ Id: 3
, Name: 'Facility Location 2', value: 'facilityLoc_2', Selected: false }), Object({ Id: 4, Name: 'Facility Location 3', value: 'facilityLoc_3', Selected: false }) ].
            at Object.<anonymous> (test/PatientListControllerSpec.js:9:2664)`

Comment: @tanmay let me try that

Comment: @tanmay I am getting the following error message after using expect(arrayName).toContain('object(s)')..
`Expected undefined to contain Object({ Id: 1, Name: 'All', value: 'all', Selected: true }), Object({ Id: 2, Name: 'Facility Location 1', value: 'facilityLoc_1', Selected: true }), Object({ Id: 3, Name: 'Facility Location 2', value: 'facilityLoc_2', Selected: false }), Object({ Id: 4, Name: 'Facility Location 3', value: 'facilityLoc_3', Selected: false }).
    at Object.&lt;anonymous&gt; (test/PatientListControllerSpec.js:9:2664)`

Answer (score 0):

//you have to inject controller and define scope

```
beforeEach(inject(function($controller,$rootScope,_$httpBackend_,_$http_){

           controller = $controller('Ctrl', {
                        $scope: scope
                                    });
           }));
```

//use scope instead of $scope in "it" function